# What does Dataset's as method really mean

Tags: apache-spark

I have simple code:

```
  test("Dataset as method") {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("Dataset as method").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    //xyz is an alias of ds1
    val ds1 = Seq("1", "2").toDS().as("xyz")
    //xyz can be used to refer to the value column  
    ds1.select($"xyz.value").show(truncate = false)
    //ERROR here, no table or view named xyz
    spark.sql("select * from xyz").show(truncate = false)
  }
```

It looks to me that `xyz` is like a table name, but the sql `select * from xyz` raises an error complaining `xyz` doesn't exist.

So, I want to ask, what does `as` method really mean? and how I should use the alias,like `xyz` in my case

Comment: You are missing a temp table registration

Comment: Without   table registration, But i can `ds1.select($"xyz.value").show(truncate = false)`

Comment: Yes... `xyz` is a column there, not a table. `ds1` is the table... Try `ds1.printSchema()`. `as()` renames a column, not registers a SparkSQL table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.as()` when used with `dataset` (as in your case) is a function to create `alias` for a `dataset` as you can see in the `api doc`

```
  /**
   * Returns a new Dataset with an alias set.
   *
   * @group typedrel
   * @since 1.6.0
   */
  def as(alias: String): Dataset[T] = withTypedPlan {
    SubqueryAlias(alias, logicalPlan)
  }
```

which can be used in function apis only such as `select`, `join`, `filter` etc. But the *alias* cannot be used for *sql queries*.

It is **more evident** if you *create two columns dataset and use alias* as you did

```
val ds1 = Seq(("1", "2"),("3", "4")).toDS().as("xyz")
```

Now you can use `select` to *select only one column using the alias* as

```
ds1.select($"xyz._1").show(truncate = false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+
|_1 |
+---+
|1  |
|3  |
+---+
```

**The use of `as` alias is more evident when you do `join` of two datsets having same column names where you can write condition for joining using the alias.**

But *to use alias for use in sql queries you will have to register* the table

```
ds1.registerTempTable("xyz")
spark.sql("select * from xyz").show(truncate = false)
```

which should give you the correct result

```
+---+---+
|_1 |_2 |
+---+---+
|1  |2  |
|3  |4  |
+---+---+
```

Or even better do it in a new way

```
ds1.createOrReplaceTempView("xyz")
```